# Facebook Messenger: online or offline?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I'm having friends come up in the chat bar that have no green dot next to their name. I'm just wanting to know if they are online or not?  Some have green dots and some don't. Is it possible that the person is online but has clicked on appear offline?  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

No, it isn't possible to know if someone if online and has just set their status as offline. It may arise a privacy concern.

But there's a way to know if someone is online or not by checking their profile, check if they recently liked status, page or anything which can indicate that they are active. But it won't always work.

**Update:** 
There's another trick which can tell you if an user is active or not. Setup a group chat on Facebook by sending a message to more than one friend (also add the friends you want to know active status of) and then send a random message, now when someone in the group chat will see the message, there will be a notification like `Seen by [name]` and if your friends see the message, the notification will be shown for them too.

Comment: thanks heaps for your reply. Ive done that and checked for any recent activity and none came up.Its weird cos its been doing that for on and off for the last couple of days and I know she (my sister in law) hasn t been online. Is it possible that someone else has her login details and is logging in but disabling chat?

Comment: Ohh, if you doubt someone else is using her FB account, tell your sister-in-law to change the password as soon as possible and also check their account settings for suspicious activities.

Comment: yeah ive double checked her account settings for her and they are all good. Ill tell her to change her password asap. thanks heaps for your feedback.

Comment: @Emma I updated the answer, check the it.

Answer (score 0):

You can. At the bottom of the screen there is a “people” button. Click on that and it will show your friends. If they have the Messenger sign (lightning sign) then they're online. If not they're offline.